# Possible error in book Zero to Monero: Second Edition

Tags: cryptography, algorithm, elliptic-curve

I am reading the book [Zero to Monero: Second Edition](https://www.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-2-0-0.pdf) from the [GetMonero Library](https://www.getmonero.org/library/).

On the 3rd paragraph of page 15, the book mentions an algorithm for finding points inside the subgroup of order `l`, given an elliptic curve group of order `N`.

If I understand correctly, the group is assumed to be cyclic. Since in the last paragraph of page 14, it is assumed that `P'` is a generator.

Since the group is cyclic, we can identify it with `Z/(N) = {0, P', 2P', ..., (N - 1)P'}` where `P'` is a generator. Put `h = 2, l = 3`, then `N = 6` and the subgroup of order `l` is `Z/(l) = {0, 2P', 4P'}`.

Next we want to check if `5P'` is in `Z/(l)`. Now `2(5P') = 10P' = 4P' != 0 mod 6`. So by the algorithm, `5P'` is in `Z/(l)`! But this clearly contradicts `Z/(l) = {0, 2P', 4P'}`.

Is this an error or am I misunderstand something?

**Edit:** My initial question is confusing. I modify it to specify `P'` as a generator to make it easier to distinguish between EC points and scalars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this an error or am I misunderstand something?

No it is not an error, you are misunderstanding.

> Since the group is cyclic, we can identify it with... Next we check if 5 is in...

Group elements are EC points, not scalars.

> Now 2 · 5 ...

In the book, page 15 bullet 3, `hP` is a *point* multiplication, i.e. point `P` added to itself `h` times.

**UPDATE** *incorporating your question edits above and comments below*

With an initial group of `{0, P, 2P, 3P, 4P, 5P}` then using point `2P` to select a subgroup with order `l = 3`, we have the subgroup `{0, 2P, 4P}`.

Now per the book, selecting a random point (`5P` in this example), we have:

```
h = N/l = 6/3 = 2
P' = 5P
P = hP' = 2P' = 4P
```

Again per the book, because `P` (here `P = hP' = 2P' = 4P`) is not `0`, it is in the subgroup of order `l = 3`, which we can see is correct, `4P` is indeed in the subgroup `{0, 2P, 4P}`.

I believe your confusion is this:

> So by the algorithm, `5P'` is in `Z/(l)`!

This statement is incorrect. Using your notation, the algorithm is *actually* saying `2(5P')` is in `Z/(l)`.

Comment: Hello jtgrassie. Thanks for answering. My initial question is confusing. I modify it to specify `P'` as a generator to make it easier to distinguish between EC points and scalars.

Comment: I've now fixed that confusing notation. What I really mean is `2(5P') = 10P' = 4P' mod 6`.

Comment: If your initial group has points `{0, P, 2P, 3P, 4P, 5P}` (so order of 6) then the subgroup *generated* using `5P` would have the same order and set of points (i.e. by adding 5P to itself until it reaches `I` yields the same set of points, `{5P, 4P, 3P, 2P, P, 0}`).

Comment: Suppose the initial group has points `{0, P', 2P', 3P', 4P', 5P'}`. In step 1, we choose the subgroup order to be `l = 3`, so the subgroup is generated by `2P'`, with elements `{0, 2P', 4P'}`. In step 2, `5P'` is the random point chosen.

Comment: And `2(5P) = 4P` which is in the subgroup `{0, 2P, 4P}` because `2(5P)` is not 0.